# How to find Server on the LAN - Using VB.Net [Visual Studio 2010]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**I am going to develop Online Examination System in VB.Net for LAN.**

> > I need to find server at run-time so that I can able to attach server Name (or Path) to the connection string (of a particular instance of application on client pc) programaticaly.

**Is it possible to find server of the LAN using VB.Net ?**

Suggestions in the discussion will be appreciated . . .Thanks in advance.

> **P.s. -** I do not want to go and setup the PCs every time for any one. It should be easy & one-click setup of the application.
>   ---Please suggest the either ways .

Comment: _Server_ is too broad definition. Please specify what kind of server are you talking about

Comment: @Steve : Server of LAN....where i am going to install my vb.net application with Sql Server database.

Comment: What is "server of LAN"? Do you mean LAN as for "Local Area Network" or something else?

Comment: Yes @ajakblackgoat ...Server of Local Area Network.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Browser is a windows service that is generally installed with SQL server.  It listens for broadcast messages and provides information on the installed SQL server instances of the machine.

The .NET Framework has built-in functionality to discover all SQL Servers in the local network by sending a broadcast message and listening for responses by SQL Server Browser services.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you look at the example in the provided link, you will see that what you get are the **hosts and instances** of all SQL Servers on the local network.  This can be reused as-is in a connection string.  Obviously it won't return any login credentials; these will have to be hardcoded in your app.

Comment: Can u please explain little more . . .what will be the connection string for client pc ?